# JOLT Transforming Date and Time to Timestamp

Tags: json, jolt

My Input Json has separate Date and Time fields.
The format of the Date field is YYMMDD.
The format of the Time field is HHMMSS.

```
{
  "DATE": "20201123",
  "TIME": "100923"
}
```

I try to convert it to a timestamp. Here my Spec.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "DATE": "tmp_Date",
      "TIME": "tmp_Time"
    }
  },
  {
    // Create Timestamp
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "tmp_Year": "=substring(@(1,tmp_Date),0,4)",
      "tmp_Month": "=substring(@(1,tmp_Date),4,6)",
      "tmp_Day": "=substring(@(1,tmp_Date),6,8)",
      "tmp_Hours": "=substring(@(1,tmp_Time),0,2)",
      "tmp_Minutes": "=substring(@(1,tmp_Time),2,4)",
      "tmp_Seconds": "=substring(@(1,tmp_Time),4,6)",
      // Prior to this line, only temporary fields were created from substrings as preparation for the timestamp concatenateion
      "timeStamp": "=concat(@(1,tmp_Year),'-',@(1,tmp_Month),'-',@(1,tmp_Day),'T',@(1,tmp_Hours),':',@(1,tmp_Minutes),':',@(1,tmp_Seconds),'Z')"
    }
},
  {
    // Remove temporary substring fields
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "tmp_*": ""
    }
    }
]
```

My Output is:

```
{
  "timeStamp" : "2020-11-23T10:09:23Z"
}
```

Is there a better way to convert the date and time field to a timestamp ?

Comment: Jolt doesn't have Date Time Utilities, Date Time operations can be done only through `modify-default-beta`